# Send data packets from one linux server to other server (LINUX)

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am new to C programming. 
I have two Linux machine. I want to send some data packets from one Linux machine to other Linux machine.
Please suggest some references.
I found so many things on net, and bit confused how to proceed.
Please suggest.

Comment: Google for socket programming.

Comment: Read [Beej's network programming guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html).

Comment: @KerrekSB Beej's guide is an abomination. Please don't forward the use of it any further. To the OP: Steven's networking books are what you should be reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from scratch with both C and networking is a bit tough, but the best online sockets tutorial would be [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

If you are serious about learning network programming though, get this book - you'll never regret: [UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1](http://www.unpbook.com/) by W. Richard Stevens.

Comment: And again for this horrible guide. Note to readers of this: alarm(3) is not the proper way to time out from socket reads. Apparently Beej had never heard of select(3) or poll(3)

Comment: @tbert: isn't there a [whole chapter on `select`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select)?

Comment: Yes, Stevens is the bible, but out of free online guides ... suggest better ones.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov how about working code from software that isn't written by people whose best contribution to society would be writing a worm to erase their previous work? At least, that's how I learned to do it

Comment: @tbert, contribute references, not rants.